# Symonfy 6.4 #[AsEntityListener] PostFlush doesn't work

Tags: symfony, events, doctrine

Working now with symfony 6.4 I'm trying to convert some on my service definition (.yml) into php attributes.
What I'm doing is deleting the service definition of an EntityListener and replacing it with the corresponding PHP attributes.

It works for the some events (PreUpdate/PostUpdate) events but the postFlush is never called... What am I doing wrong?

Before in service.yml:

```
    App\Listener\Task\TaskCompletedListener:
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postFlush }
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preUpdate }
```

After in my Listener class.php

```
<?php


namespace App\Listener\Task;

use App\Entity\Task\Task;
use App\Entity\Task\TaskUserLog;
use App\Entity\User\User;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Attribute\AsEntityListener;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PostFlushEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Events;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;

#[AsEntityListener(event: Events::preUpdate, method: 'preUpdate', entity: Task::class)]
#[AsEntityListener(event: Events::postFlush, method: 'postFlush', entity: Task::class)]
class TaskCompletedListener
{

    private $taskUserLog=null;
  
    private TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    public function preUpdate(Task $task, PreUpdateEventArgs $args){


        if($args->hasChangedField('lastCompletionDate')){

            //Log new entry to see who did the task
            $taskUserLog=new TaskUserLog();

            /** @var User $user */
            $user=$this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
            $taskUserLog->setUser($user);
            $taskUserLog->setTask($task);

            $this->taskUserLog=$taskUserLog;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param Task $task
     * @param PostFlushEventArgs $event
     */
    public function postFlush(Task $task, PostFlushEventArgs $event)
    {

        if(!is_null($this->taskUserLog)) {

            $em = $event->getObjectManager();

            $em->persist($this->taskUserLog);
            $this->taskUserLog=null;
            $em->flush();
        }
    }
}
```

I think the symfony docs are clear enough and the change simple, but I don't know why it doesn't work. Is it only one event per class?

[https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/events.html#:~:text=%24event%20argument](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/events.html#:%7E:text=%24event%20argument)).-,Doctrine%20Entity%20Listeners,is%20modified%20in%20the%20database.

UPDATE
The events works for PreUpdate/PostUpdate but not PostFlush...

Here is my doctrine.yaml

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver:   pdo_mysql
    host:     "%database_host%"
    port:     "%database_port%"
    dbname:   "%database_name%"
    user:     "%database_user%"
    password: "%database_password%"
    charset:  UTF8
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"

    entity_managers:
        default:
            mappings:
                App:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: attribute
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                    prefix: 'App\Entity'
                    alias: App
            naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
            auto_mapping: true
            query_cache_driver:
                type: service
                id: doctrine.cache.memcached
            result_cache_driver:
                type: service
                id: doctrine.cache.memcached

            filters:
                softdeleteable:
                    class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
                    enabled: true
            dql:
                string_functions:
                    MONTH: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Month
                    YEAR: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year
                    DAY: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Day
                    DATE: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Date
                    GROUP_CONCAT: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\GroupConcat
```

Comment: OMG, thanks for the solution :) I spent several hours making something like this...

Answer (score 0):

After testing, I have found out that using the following attributes work:

```
#[AsEntityListener(entity: Order::class, event: Events::preUpdate,method: "preUpdate")]

#[AsDoctrineListener(event: Events::postFlush)]
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think we need to do this because a postFlush event is only a Doctrine Lifecycle events and not an Entity Event.

Here is the link to the doctrine documentation specifying which event is linked to an entity lifecycle callback: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/reference/events.html#events-overview